# mysql returned an empty result set upon executing a trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

i am trying to create a trigger but i  do not know why I am getting this message. am i doing the right this or am I doing something wrong? when I try to run the trigger im getting a message like

```
# MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows).
```

this is my trigger

```
    DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS admin.catch_insert//

    CREATE TRIGGER admin.catch_insert BEFORE INSERT ON adminpanel.users
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO admin.usertrigger(cmd, time, cmd_user, email, phone_number) VALUES("INSERT", NOW(), CURRENT_USER(), new.email, new.phone_number);
    END
//
```

what causes this and is ther anything im doing wrongly??may someone please expalain to me what i can do or how i can go about it??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong.

The message you got is the standard message returned after a successful INSERT statement. (It returns no rows to you, it just adds one in your table)

Comment: but its supposed to say query return succefully

Comment: instead its giving me that message